# Finding paths between two classes in OWL-DL

Tags: semantic-web, owl, description-logic

In DL (and OWL-DL): Given a TBox, two concepts *C1* and *C2*, in my problem, we say that a **path** exists between *C1* and *C2* ***if and only if***:

> C1 ⊑ =1 r.C2     where r is a single/composite role (role chain)

i.e. if *r* is a **single** role then we must have each instance of *C1* related to **exactly one** instance of *C2* through *r*; otherwise (r is **composite**) then each instance of *C1* is related to **exactly one** instance of *C2* through a **composition** of roles i.e. (r1*r2*r3...) if we consider * stands for role composition.

My question is: Is the **Graph** sense the best way to accomplish this task using *OWL API*, where graph *nodes* stand for *concepts* and *edges* stand for *object properties*. Then we start from *C1* node and perform a **breadth-first** search until we reach *C2*. This is my idea! Is there any better way to perform this?

This problem is generally about fining paths which have specific characteristics between two ontology concepts. For the ease of understaning, you can eliminate the exactly one restriction. Thus

> C1 ⊑ ∃ r.C2

Comment: I'm not sure offhand, but I *think* that if you have an axiom like `C1 subClassOf (p o q) exactly 1 C2`, i.e., the kind of axiom you're talking about, then you're not in OWL-DL anymore, because of the restrictions on where complex properties can appear.

Comment: It helps very much that you provided the sample axiom, but I'm not exactly clear what you're asking.  Are you asking to find C1, C2, and values of r such that "C1 ⊑ =1 r.C2"?  You can't do that through a search on an RDF graph of some instance data, because such graph is only one model of the data.

Comment: You *could*, I suppose, start from a class A, and then iterate through declared relations r and classes B asking *whether* (A subClassOf r exactly 1 B).  Of course, in that case, you'll still have the issue of class and relation *expressions* (i.e., non-atomic classes like (A or (B and (not C))) and relations like (inverse r)).

Comment: Your last "axiom", "C1 ⊑ r.C2", doesn't make sense, because "r.C2" isn't a class expression.

Comment: For the the last axiom I edited it, I meant C1 ⊑ ∃r.C2.

Comment: For the basic question, consider C1 and C2 are constants, and I'm searching for all r such that C1 ⊑ =1 r.C2.

Comment: Finding such values of r isn't a typical DL reasoner task, though some reasoners might support it.  You'd still have to, I think, iterate through the properties that you know, and ask about each one.

Comment: Besides, I have no individuals in my ontology, just the TBox.

Comment: Well, then is a graph the best way as I mentioned in the basic question?

Comment: OK, will any of the "A subClassOf r exactly 1 B" links be inferred, or all explicitly declared?  If they'll all be explicitly declared, then it sounds like just retrieving all of those, and building a graph and doing a graph search might be the best way to do this.

Comment: explicitly declared, if not, I need to do that at some stage before launching this work.

Comment: OK, so if they're all explicitly declared, you can simply ask for all A, r, and B, such that (A subClassOf r exactly 1 B), and do a graph search (BFS or DFS, doesn't really matter if you want *all* paths, since the graph is finite and you won't follow cycles) to enumerate the paths.

Comment: That sounds good, but at each step, I can only ask for r such that A, such that (A subClassOf r exactly 1 B) (A and B are constants).

Comment: I mean at each iteration, only **one** simple objectProberty r can be discovered a time, and the graph sense is for the composition. Is this right?

Comment: You said you'd have all the axioms of that form declared in advance. You can just construct a graph from them with one edge per axiom.

Comment: Yes, by 'discovered', I mean 'processed'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67492/discussion-between-median-hilal-and-joshua-taylor).

Comment: Please a last question, if they are not clearly declared, what is the other idea? an please move your comment about that using graph is the right way to an answer in order to tick it as a solution.

Comment: It depends.  You might have a reasoner which can find values for r such that (A subClassOf r exactly 1 B).  If you don't have a reasoner that can do that, then you could iterate through the properties and chains and classes that appear in your ontology and ask whether for each r and B it is true that (A subClassOf r exactly 1 B).

Comment: But again, even if I have this reasoner, it can be used for a simple role r,  each time. i.e. this reasoner cannot be used for chains. Again chains need iteration or graph etc.

Comment: That would depend on the reasoner, wouldn't it?

Comment: Disregarding sparql, I think reasoners cannot handle composite roles. If it comes to sparql, using a reasoner for such a task makes sense. But for my problem, there are no individuals, so I think using sparql is not suitable. Am I right?

Comment: (i) "I think reasoners cannot handle composite roles."  I'm not sure what you mean here.  They are part of of OWL-DL, and reasoners such as Pellet handle composite roles.  E.g., if you assert that (A subClassOf p some B) and (B subClassOf q some C), you can infer that A subClassof some (p o q) C).  (ii) "there are no individuals, so I think using sparql is not suitable"  You can still use SPARQL to query the RDF serialization of your OWL ontology.  That would help to retrieve all the edges in the graph that you need to traverse, but it won't help much for actually finding those paths.

Comment: (i) I tried Protege 5.0 with Pellet out for  " if you assert that (A subClassOf p some B) and (B subClassOf q some C), you can infer that A subClassof some (p o q) C)", it's not working. Anyway, regarding what you say, a reasoner cannot be used when those p and q are variables, i.e. it cannot be used to find p1 o p2 o ... o pn such that A subClassOf some p1 o p2 o ... o pn B. where p1, p2, ..., pn are not known

Comment: Protege is not the only way to interact with Pellet.  Pellet can be connected to SPARQL engines, which means that you *can* write SPARQL queries that use variables in the place of properties, and have Pellet provide solutions.  There is more to reasoner interaction than Protege.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable information. To conclude our discussion, having an ontology O and A and B concepts and in order to find all p such that p = p1 o p2 o ... o pn where A subClassOf some p1 o p2 o ... o pn B. We have to retrieve all classes and properties of the ontology and find some (programmatically) way to complete this task. A graph seems a suitable candidate.